# Вызов модели в конструторе класса. Opencart

Tags: php, ооп, opencart

В ходе работы с opencart (v2). У меня возник вопрос. Правильно ли с точки зрения ООП, вызывать модели в конструкторе класса.
Пример:

```
<?php
class ControllerAccountAccount extends Controller
{
    public function __construct($registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry);
        $this->load->model('account/account');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        
    }
}
```